# Are deceptive redirect hyperlinks safe to use in emails?

Tags: email, html-email

We're generating some emails programmatically. We need to include a hyperlink that takes people to a page on website A, but we want to use website B to track their click before redirecting.

Is it safe to show the URL to website A, but in a hyperlink that really takes them to website B? That is, something like this:

```
Here's the page you wanted:
<a href="http://website-b.com/someTrackingToken">
    website-a.com/theThingYouWereExpecting
</a>
```

... or does this look sufficiently scam-like that some email clients might object to it?

Note:

- We specifically *do* want the website-a.com URL to be visible to the email recipient.
- The sites are on different domains.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the visible link and the `href` property to be two totally different things and there's usually little to no consequences, this is pretty standard for most mailers that need tracking.

The thing is, why not just wrap some text instead of a literal link? Present it as a button if you're worried about "click ability".

If you want to present a link that's nearly the same, why not just append some parameters on the end that trigger the tracking action? Like `/x` vs `/x?token=XXX` where you can grab that and and process it at any point of handling the request. Just suppress the display of that in the raw URL you're showing.